# How do you navigate to the end of the page in Visual Studios Code on Linux Mint / Ubuntu

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I have like a thousand line of code and multiple .js pages. It's pretty annoying holding down the arrow keys and waiting till the cursor reaches the end. Or holding down the arrow keys and scrolling to the beginning. I tried everything I could think of like using the shift, ctrl, alt, buttons, arrows, nothing works! How do I navigate to the bottom of the page and back to home? I'm using Linux Mint / Ubuntu. Thanks

Comment: Normally it's Ctrl+Home and Ctrl+End. Or are you using a notebook which doesn't have Home/End keys?

Comment: ctrl home/end doesn't work. It's a brand new lenovo ideapad 330S running Linux Mint 19.1. It has the arrow keys and the home/end button. thanks for your response

Answer (score 1):

`Home/End` should take you to the beginning/end of the line, and `Ctrl + Home/End` should take you to the beginning/end of the file. See https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-linux.pdf for some helpful tips for Linux.

Alternatively, if you're more familiar with Vim or keybindings from other apps, VSCode may have packages to support them.

Comment: thanks for your response. ctrl home/end doesn't work. It's a brand new lenovo ideapad 330S running Linux Mint 19.1. It works on my pc but not on the linux, it's really strange. I tried a lot of key combos nothing worked for me

Comment: I think I may have to do this: VSCode may have packages to support them. thanks